# Can't save keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

When I press "I" and select "LocRotScale" function it `doesn't save the keyframe`.
[image: It says keying set failed to insert any keyframes]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've selected *Bone.009* but it's locked as we see in the left panel. Maybe you've locked this track by accident, for example with the shortcut <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thank you <3 :*

Comment: you must have locked this track by accident, for example with the shortcut Tab  ;)